# Couch has apparent limit of attachment sizes on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, couchdb, attachment

I have plain vanilla CouchDB from Apache, which runs as an App running on a Mac OS X 10.9. If I try to attach an attachment to a document that is above 1 Meg in size, it just hangs and does nothing.

I have tried to use couchdbs on Linux, and there the sky is the limit.

I first thought it had to do with low limits on the mac but it doesn't seem so :

```
➜  ~  ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-u: processes                       709
-n: file descriptors                256
```

What is causing this ? Why ? And how to fix this ?

Comment: Thats strange. The problem might be on the client side. What client are you using to add the document ? Can you reproduce this with simple curl request (PUT on /dbname/doc_id/attachment_name) ?

Comment: I tried this with python and the couchdb module, but this is also inside futon, the web interface to couch. I will repeat, this only happens on a mac, not linux. Just create a database, create a doc and then click on add attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the config files given by `couchdb -c`. You probably have this somewhere in them (for some unknown reason):

```
[couchdb]
max_attachment_size = 1048576 ; bytes
```

Remove or comment the line and you should be fine.

Or maybe it was compiled with this hardcoded so you could add this line to one of the config file and increase the value.

---

#### Update

`max_attachment_size` is undocumented so probably not safe to use. I leave the original answer as it seems to have solved the problem of the OP but according to [the docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/), the attachment size should be unlimited. Also [`attachment_stream_buffer_size`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/couchdb.html#couchdb/attachment_stream_buffer_size) is the config key controlling the chunk size of the attachments which might relevant.

Comment: This did the trick. Phew. This variable is nowhere to be seen, just added it and voila, I can upload much larger files now.

Comment: @Simon a bit wonder where did you find this option since there is no such for CouchDB (:

Comment: @Kxepal I supposed I guessed it from the existence of `max_document_size`. Then I googled it and found [this thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/200902.mbox/%3C5aaed53f0902211118t43d0e4dfxaa62bddb80ac64c2@mail.gmail.com%3E) to confirm it existed.

Comment: @Simon suddenly, it doesn't. `max_document_size` is actually limits all POST data size, not only documents. Attachments size couldn't be limited by config option since they are transfered by chunks and this chunks could be limited via `attachment_stream_buffer_size` option.

Comment: @Kxepal Ok. From [the docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/couchdb.html) it seems that `max_attachment_size` is undocumented, possibly because it was either removed or was never documented. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Simon I wrote this docs and sure that there was never such(: the closest similar is `max_attachment_chunk_size`, but it's removed since 1.0 - that's around 3 years ago.